# aiohttp Client Connection Error, however I can find the website online just fine?

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I am attempting to return the HTTP request code from a list of urls asynchronously using this code I found online, however after a few printed I receive the error ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host website_i_removed :80 ssl:None [getaddrinfo failed]. As the website is valid I am confused on how it says I cannot connect. If I am doing this wrong at any point please point me in the right direction.

The past few hours I have been looking into the documentation and online for aiohttp, but they dont have an example on HTTP requests with a list of urls, and their getting started page in the docs is quite hard to follow since I am brand new to async programming. Below is the code I am using, assume urls is a list of strings.

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def fetch(url, session):
async with session.get(url) as response:
    code_status = response.history[0].status if response.history else response.status
    print('%s -> Status Code: %s' % (url, code_status))
    return await response.read()


async def bound_fetch(semaphore, url, session):
# Getter function with semaphore.
async with semaphore:
    await fetch(url, session)


async def run(urls):
tasks = []
# create instance of Semaphore
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(1000)

async with ClientSession() as session:
    for url in urls:
        # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(semaphore, url, session))
        tasks.append(task)

    responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    await responses

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(urls))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

I expected each website to print its request code to determine if they are reachable, however it says I can't connect to some despite me being able to look them up in my browser.